# Change text (html) with .animate

Tags: jquery, html, text, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate the html part of a tag ( `<font id="test" size="7">This Text!</font>` ) using jQuery's Animate function, like so:

```
$("#test").delay(1500).animate({text:'The text has now changed!'},500);
```

However nothing happens, it does not change the text.

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to change text 'smoothly', you might use two `<span>`s overlapping and do some work. Or if you just want to change text 'instantly', you can use `.text()`.  PS : You may use `<span style="..">` for styling instead of `<font ..>`.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The [`animate(..)`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function' signature is:

```
.animate( properties, options );
```

And it says the following about the parameter `properties`:

> properties A map of CSS properties that
>   the animation will move toward.

`text` is not a CSS property, this is why the function isn't working as you expected.

Do you want to fade the text out? Do you want to move it? I might be able to provide an alternative.

Have a look at the [following fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jWcLz/1/).

Comment: I would like the text to change, with the effect that the old text fades out, while the new text fades in :)

Comment: How do you make the old text come back when the cursor hovers away?

Comment: why use an external link while it's just few lines of code?

Answer (score 12):

```
$("#test").hide(100, function() {
    $(this).html("......").show(100);
});
```

> Updated:

Another easy way:

```
$("#test").fadeOut(400, function() {
    $(this).html("......").fadeIn(400);
});
```

Comment: again, down voters everywhere, I used this code in production with slight modification. +1. Down-voters: Please test any code before you down vote. offending!

Comment: @wpcoder I did not vote on this answer, but I assume that it was downvoted because it is just showing some code without any explanation. Some users downvote answers without explanation as low quality answer.

Comment: The point is; dose this answer help or not, and it helped me , just changed `.show(1000)` and it worked.

Comment: With a fadeIn-fadeOut instead hide-show seems smoothest, but is a nice solution

Answer (score 4):

See Davion's anwser in this post: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26429849/1804068

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
    <span id="mySpan">Something in English</span>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#mySpan').animate({'opacity': 0}, 400, function(){
        $(this).html('Something in Spanish').animate({'opacity': 1}, 400);    
    });
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/ewtehLyc/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Following the suggestion by JiminP....

I made a jsFiddle that will "smoothly" transition between two spans in case anyone is interested in seeing this in action.  You have two main options:

1. one span fades out **at the same time as** the other span is fading in
2. one span fades out **followed by** the other span fading in.

The first time you click the button, number 1 above will occur.  The second time you click the button, number 2 will occur.  (I did this so you can visually compare the two effects.)

**Try it Out**:  http://jsfiddle.net/jWcLz/594/

*Details:*

Number 1 above (the more difficult effect) is accomplished by positioning the spans directly on top of each other via CSS with absolute positioning.  Also, the jQuery animates are not chained together, so that they can execute at the same time.

HTML

```
<div class="onTopOfEachOther">
    <span id='a'>Hello</span>
    <span id='b' style="display: none;">Goodbye</span>
</div>

<br />
<br />

<input type="button" id="btnTest" value="Run Test" />
```

CSS

```
.onTopOfEachOther {
    position: relative;
}
.onTopOfEachOther span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('#btnTest').click(function() {        
    fadeSwitchElements('a', 'b');    
}); 

function fadeSwitchElements(id1, id2)
{
    var element1 = $('#' + id1);
    var element2 = $('#' + id2);

    if(element1.is(':visible'))
    {
        element1.fadeToggle(500);
        element2.fadeToggle(500);
    }
    else
    {
         element2.fadeToggle(500, function() {
            element1.fadeToggle(500);
        });   
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you're looking to do is change the text you could do exactly as Kevin has said. But if you're trying to run an animation as well as change the text you could accomplish this by first changing the text then running your animation.

For Example:

```
$("#test").html('The text has now changed!');
$("#test").animate({left: '100px', top: '100px'},500);
```

Check out this fiddle for full example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Twig/3krLh/1/

Comment: Actually, you can curry the functions: `$(...).html(...).animate(...);`

Answer (score 1):

For fadeOut => change text => fadeIn effect
We need to animate the wrapper of texts we would like change.

Example below:

### HTML

```
<div class="timeline-yeardata">
  <div class="anime">
    <div class="ilosc-sklepow-sticker">
      <span id="amount">1400</span><br>
      sklepów
    </div>

    <div class="txts-wrap">
      <h3 class="title">Some text</h3>
      <span class="desc">Lorem ipsum description</span>
    </div>

    <div class="year-bg" id="current-year">2018</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="ch-timeline-wrap">
  <div class="ch-timeline">
    <div class="line"></div>

    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col">
        <a href="#2009" data-amount="9" data-y="2009" class="el current">
          <span class="yr">2009</span>
          <span class="dot"></span>

          <span class="title">Lorem  asdf asdf asdf a</span>
          <span class="desc">Ww wae awer awe rawer aser as</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <a href="#2010" data-amount="19" data-y="2010" class="el">
          <span class="yr">2010</span>
          <span class="dot"></span>

          <span class="title">Lorem brernern</span>
          <span class="desc">A sd asdkj aksjdkajskd jaksjd kajskd jaksjd akjsdk jaskjd akjsdkajskdj akjsd k</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### JQuery JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.ch-timeline .el').on('click', function(){

    $('.ch-timeline .el').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');

    var ilosc = $(this).data('ilosc');
    var y = $(this).data('y');
    var title = $(this).find('.title').html();
    var desc = $(this).find('desc').html();

    $('.timeline-yeardata .anime').fadeOut(400, function(){
      $('#ilosc-sklepow').html(ilosc);
      $('#current-year').html(y);
      $('.timeline-yeardata .title').html(title);
      $('.timeline-yeardata .desc').html(desc);
      $(this).fadeIn(300);
    })

  });

});
```

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

refer to [official jquery example](http://api.jquery.com/animate/): and play with it.

```
.animate({
    width: "70%",
    opacity: 0.4,
    marginLeft: "0.6in",
    fontSize: "3em",
    borderWidth: "10px"
  }, 1500 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I come up with this automatic transition using @Hoàng Vũ Tgtt 's Answer and made this.

Html

```html
<h3 id="textAnimator"></h3>
```

jQuery

```js
var currentIndex = 0;
var texts = [
  'What is Lorem Ipsum?',
  'Why do we use it?',
  'Where does it come from?',
  'Where can I get some?',
  'The standard Lorem Ipsum passage',
];

$('#textAnimator').html(texts[currentIndex]);

function animateText(){
 $('#textAnimator').animate({'opacity' : 0}, 400, function(){
   var $this = $(this);
     $('#textAnimator').html(texts[currentIndex]).animate({'opacity': 1}, 400);
     if(currentIndex == texts.length - 1){
       currentIndex = 0;
     } else {
       currentIndex += 1;
     }
 });
}

setInterval(function(){
    animateText();
}, 3000);
```