# jquery button content change and back again

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to achieve a simple feedback on a button press to fade out the button quickly, change its class and content, fade in then do the reverse back to its original state.

This is the code I thought would work fairly simply.

```
$('#event1-btn-451').fadeOut(200).toggleClass('btn-primary btn-success').html('Success!').fadeIn(200);
$('#event1-btn-451').delay(2000).fadeOut(200).toggleClass('btn-success btn-primary').html('Add Event').fadeIn(200);
```

The first line by itself works fine but if I include the second line all it does it fadeout, fadein the same 'Add Event' button with the original color, then do exactly the same thing again after the 2s delay.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2gg9G/)

First time actually posting here though of course like many I've used this for so many answers already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of animation must be chained, like this:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/2gg9G/1/)

```
$('#event1-btn-451').click(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(200, function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('btn-primary btn-success')
            .html('Success!')
            .fadeIn(200) // No need to chain as there is a delay then
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(200, function(){
                $(this).toggleClass('btn-success btn-primary')
                    .html('Add Event')
                    .fadeIn(200);
            })
        })
});
```

Comment: Thanks @toni-almeida, this was perfect. Now I comprehend the chaining on the fades.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the jQuery animate method for this instead. That was covered here.

[Change text (html) with .animate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305667/change-text-html-with-animate)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$('#event1-btn-451').click(function () {
    var _this = $(this);
    _this.fadeOut(200, function () {
        _this.toggleClass('btn-primary btn-success').html('Success!').fadeIn(200).delay(2000).fadeOut(200, function () {
            console.log('c');
            _this.toggleClass('btn-success btn-primary').html('Add Event').fadeIn(200);
        })
    });
});
```

use `callback function` of jquery `fadeOut()`

Comment: Very similar to Toni's response for the required chaining but I'm wondering what the console.log('c) is for?