# jQuery: Animate on change of .innerHTML or .text

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm translating my site by dynamically changing the text on the website with jQuery like this:

```
<span id="mySpan">Something in English</span>

$('#mySpan').html("Something else in Spanish");
```

It works great but, due to changes in the length of the text, it's a hard transition, the new text just appears and parent element is resizing instantly.

Is there an easy way to animate/ease the transition during the change of text? Like Fadeing and/or resizing nicely?

I know it's possible with hidden elements, but because I have lot's of text, I don't want to load this if not needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, if your `span` element has a parent, e.g.:

```
<div class="parent">
    <span id="mySpan">Something in English</span>
</div>
```

you could do it like this:

```
$('#mySpan').animate({'opacity': 0}, 400, function(){
        $(this).html('Something in Spanish').animate({'opacity': 1}, 400);    
    });
```

Basically, you animate child `span`'s opacity to 0, `400` is `transition time` in ms. After that action is done, you do a callback function which replaces `span`'s `html` with wanted text while it still has `opacity: 0`, and then you do backwards animation to `opacity: 1`.

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/ewtehLyc/1/)