# jQuery count large numbers up

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery animate to increment numbers in 1 second.

```js
$({ count: 0 }).animate({ count: 12000 }, {
  duration: 1000,
  easing: 'swing',
  step: function() {
    let mathCount = Math.ceil(this.count).toLocaleString('en');
    $('.my-element').text(mathCount);
  },
  complete: function() {
    console.log('finished')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="my-element"></span>
```

I'm also using `toLocaleString()` to add decimal commas.

When I'm counting large numbers like `12000` it reaches `11,998` or less. Why is this happening?

If i increase the duration for more than a second it will work. How can I reach the correct number without changing the duration?

Comment: Not an answer to your _"why"_ question but you could always set the correct final number in the `complete` hook. My guess as to why is that jQuery is using `setTimeout` or `setInterval` which are never precise

Comment: I don't understand `$({count: 0}).animate()`. The `animate()` method should be called on a jQuery object representing a DOM element, and it's used to change its CSS gradually.

Comment: @Barmar jQuery isn't fussy. You can wrap arbitrary JS objects / arrays in `jQuery`

Comment: It gets to 12000 in the snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation for the `.animate()` API](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) I think the answer may be as simple as **you are not using `.animate()` for its intended purpose.**  Any usage above and beyond what is documented is not guaranteed to work (and likely may not).

I say this because the documentation states that `.animate()` is intended to:

> Perform a custom animation of a set of CSS properties.

All the document show the initial object passed in that is chained off of as a CSS selector, *not* an arbitrary object.  All the examples additionally show that the properties passed as the first arg to `.animate()` are to be an object of valid CSS properties.

Of particular note is the intended purpose of `.step()`:

> A function to be called for each animated property of each animated element. **This function provides an opportunity to modify the Tween object to change the value of the property *before it is set.***

(emphasis added)

Based on this reading, `.step` is *only* intended to adjust the value, and then jQuery will internally take the adjusted value and apply it to the element in question.  However, you are circumventing this process, and using it to directly manipulate the element *yourself*.

If I had to venture a guess, I would say that for the *final* update in the animate cycle, step is *skipped*, because there should be no need for adjustment because jQuery assumes it is simply setting the ultimate final value of CSS.  As was stated in the comments of the question, you *could* simply use the `complete` hook to set it, but ultimately you are abusing/misusing the `.animate()` method and when working outside of the documented API you are opening yourself up to potential breaks in behavior with library updates.  I would instead recommend exploring a different means of achieving this effect that doesn't leverage undocumented, unintended usage of the jQuery API.

*(Update: While not *quite* a duplicate [this answer from a similar question asking how to update text content with `animate()` provides a similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6305773/6831341)...)*

Comment: Thanks! I believe this is the correct answer. I have found an alternative solution.

Comment: Glad to hear this helped you!  You _might_ consider posting your own answer on this question showing the alternative solution you implemented so that other visitors to this post can understand how you solved the problem.  Good luck, and happy coding!